# Set up a MBR on one drive to boot debian on another drive

Tags: linux, hard-drive, boot, debian, grub

I trashed my old version of debian while trying to update it on my main disk (sda). I installed the latest debian version on sdb which runs great. I tried to change the boot order in the BIOS but it doesn't seem to support that capability (Lenovo Thinkpad T430). So when I boot the machine I have to manually select the second drive as the boot drive.

Can I just install grub into the MBR on sda with grub from sdb?
Something like grub-install /dev/sda while running debian from sdb.

Thanks

Comment: You probably can but why? Just change the boot order in BIOS (assuming it has BIOS instead of the modern UEFI for which you should have installed the OSes in UEFI mode and wouldn't be here asking ;)).

Comment: It appears that you have created a new account and lost access to this question. Please use the [contact] form at the bottom of the page and select "I need to merge accounts" You will then be able to edit, comment on and potentially accept answers to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a Grub2 installed in the first sectors of `/dev/hda` and its `/boot/grub` elsewhere. Normally, `grub-install` search its `/boot/grub` and make all things ok.